# Django 404 on POST request

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send a form via POST on my site, however, it appears the first part of the POST URL is being chopped off leading to it not being able to match the correct url.

The form I'm trying to send in the template:

```
<form action= "{% url 'change_portrait' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h5>Edit Portrait</h5>
        <input type="hidden" name="portrait_id" value="{{image.pk}}">
        <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Changes</button>
</form>
```

which correctly renders to:

```
<form action= "/AdminDashboard/EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/" method="post">
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='iCt1xvIc1KZXErhbcMNepk2daHXApGih' />
        <h5>Edit Portrait</h5>
        <input type="hidden" name="portrait_id" value="14">
        <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Changes</button>
</form>
```

The action URL is correct, and is where I want the form to be submitted to. However, when the form is submitted I get a 404 with the following message:

```
Using the URLconf defined in ZachWebsite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^AdminDashboard/
^ ^SundayPortraits/ [name='sunday_portraits']
^ ^Contact/ [name='contact_submission']
^ ^SubmitOrder/ [name='submit_buy_order']
^ ^BuyPrint/ [name='buy_print']
^ ^$ [name='index']
^ ^Login [name='login']
^ ^Logout [name='logout']
^ ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/, didn't match any of these.
```

Here is my base urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^AdminDashboard/', include('AdminDashboard.urls')),
url(r'^', include('mainApp.urls'))
]
```

And AdminDashboard.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/', views.change_portrait, name='change_portrait'),
url(r'^EditPortraits/', views.edit_portraits, name='edit_portraits'),
url(r'^', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

For some reason unbeknownst to me submitting the form cuts off the initial '/AdminDashboard/' and only tests against the remaining url 'EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/'. This of course causes it to skip over the first url pattern in the base urls.py (where it should go) and instead match with the catch all second url and subsequently fail to match all the urls in mainApp.urls. I cannot for the life of me figure out why submitting the form cuts off the first section of the action URL. It works as intended on the built in django development server but fails when deployed to the production server.

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

EDIT

mainApp.urls (these are what are shown in the trace but should never be attempted in the first place):

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^SundayPortraits/', views.sunday_portraits, name='sunday_portraits'),
url(r'^Contact/', views.contact, name='contact_submission'),
url(r'^SubmitOrder/', views.submit_buy_order, name='submit_buy_order'),
url(r'^BuyPrint/', views.buy_print, name='buy_print'),
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^Login', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^Logout', views.logout, name='logout')
]
```

views.change_portrait:

```
def change_portrait(request):
    return HttpResponse('in')
```

This never shows which means it never gets to the view.

EDIT 2:

It should also be noted that on form submission the url in my browser is correct: i.e. it shows 'mysite.com/AdminDashboard/EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/'. Django for some reason says the current URL is '/EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/'. If I go to that url ('mysite.com/AdminDashboard/EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/') regularly in my browser it correctly loads the page. It's only when I attempt to POST to that page that it fails.

EDIT 3:

The view can be updated to correctly accept the POST variables as follows:

```
def change_portrait(request):
    portrait_id = request.POST.get('portrait_id', None)
    return HttpResponse('in')
```

However the error still persists.

EDIT 4:

view that renders template:

```
def edit_portraits(request):
    if not request.session.get('logged_in', None):
        return redirect('../')

    portraits = Portrait.objects.filter(isSundayPortrait=True)
    context = {'portraits': portraits,
            'SundayPortraits': True}
    return render(request, 'AdminDashboard/editportraits.html', context)
```

Moving  url(r'^EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/', views.change_portrait, name='change_portrait') to mainApp.urls (where it goes to try to match) results in an updated mainApp.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^SundayPortraits/', views.sunday_portraits, name='sunday_portraits'),
    url(r'^Contact/', views.contact, name='contact_submission'),
    url(r'^SubmitOrder/', views.submit_buy_order, name='submit_buy_order'),
    url(r'^BuyPrint/', views.buy_print, name='buy_print'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/$', views.change_portrait, name='change_portrait'),
    url(r'^Login', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^Logout', views.logout, name='logout')
]
```

mainApp.views.change_portrait:

```
def change_portrait(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse('POST')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('GETTING')
```

Using the same form as originally shown, doing a get request results in an HttpResponse 'GETTING' as expected. Changing the form to a POST request results in a new stack trace:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://www.example.com/EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/
Raised by:  mainApp.views.change_portrait
Using the URLconf defined in ZachWebsite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^AdminDashboard/
^ ^SundayPortraits/ [name='sunday_portraits']
^ ^Contact/ [name='contact_submission']
^ ^SubmitOrder/ [name='submit_buy_order']
^ ^BuyPrint/ [name='buy_print']
^ ^$ [name='index']
^ ^EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/ [name='change_portrait']
^ ^Login [name='login']
^ ^Logout [name='logout']
^ ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, ChangePortrait/, didn't match any of these.
```

Moving to mainApp.urls (where it should catch it) now cuts off the first part of that url 'EditPortrait/' and now only tests against 'ChangePortrait/'

Comment: can you post that view as well `change_portrait` ?

Comment: The traceback doesn't display `URLs` patterns that you have in the app `AdminDashboard`

Comment: The urls from mainApp.urls, which has been now been shown above (it should in theory never attempt these). The view is just returning an HttpResponse which never happens (also now shown above).

Comment: Post your views.py.

Comment: the `view` is in **EDIT**

Comment: @Lemayzeur okay?  And how is that view properly dealing with POST requests?

Comment: I am not actually the owner of the question, just wanted to show what you asked for

Comment: @isaac328 have you tried to make your simple test a bit more helpful?   Change your view to something else.  i.e. `if request.method == 'POST': return HttpResponse("Posting") else HttpResponse("Getting").`  Then you can eliminate your form, and your urls as a problem, which is where I personally suspect you'll find your issue.  Handling your form methods.

Comment: I have. Getting working fine, posting does not.

Comment: try adding this `url(r'^EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/', views.change_portrait, name='change_portrait'),` in the same file as one of those shown in yout traceback

Comment: @isaac328 takes me back to the lack of 'change_portrait' in the listing of urls checked.

Comment: @isaac328 He is absolutely correct about the lack of `$` in your urls.  Your main project urls - understandable.  But your app urls should close every loop, or django can sometimes not know what is the start and end of a url.  Not saying this is the answer, but it's getting on my nerves :D

Comment: @isaac328, please add the view that renders the template containing the form and the view which will receive the post.

Comment: @Lemayzeur this one is all yours.  :)  Tired of asking to post code!

Comment: ok, I moved it to the mainApp.urls (where it ends up going). Will make new edit above.

Comment: Updated. I apologize, I'm trying to get everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation and testing, I seem to have figured out the problem. Turns out to be a problem with how Django is handling script_name and path_info. Because the form is posting to a sub url, the first part of the url '/AdminDashboard/' was being cut off and saved as the script_name. The remainder of the url, 'EditPortrait/ChangePortrait/' was being saved as the path_info. Django then attempted to match path_info against urls. Obviously it didn't match anything as it was missing the first part of the url that had been saved in script_name. Changing this line:

```
self.path_info = path_info
```

in django.core.handlers.wsgi.py to:

```
self.path_info = script_name + path_info
```

fixed the problem and is now working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AdminDashboard.urls`:
All your regular expressions missed the `$`

> Note: your base urls.py doesn't need to have the $ at the end

```
url(r'^EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/', 
   views.change_portrait, name='change_portrait')
```

the good one is

```
url(r'^EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/$',
    views.change_portrait, name='change_portrait')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Adding a closing $ to the regex still results in the same error unfortunately.

Comment: the traceback is the same?

Comment: Yeah, it's still cutting off "/AdminDashboard/" and only testing against "EditPortraits/ChangePortrait/" which results in the same traceback.

Comment: do you have this app well registered in INSTALLED_APPS from settings.py?

Comment: I do. See EDIT 2 for some more info. It works if I go to that url normally without posting but fails when I try to post to it. Extremely weird

Comment: better to use the `url_name` from django.urls rather than raw url in form action

Comment: @Lemayzeur hes trying to.  See the first code snippet. `{% url 'change_portrait' %}"`  The only reason he tried a raw URL is to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok, this what we're gonna.. first off edit your question with the updates, all that you have changed, start by the ''$' in your URLs, and add the whole code of the view

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean when I put the raw url into the form action. I meant when I type the url into my browser and go to it it loads and functions correctly. Even if I put the raw URL into the form action it still fails with the same error. Going to the page in my browser doesn't fail, posting to it (either with django.urls or with the raw url) does.

Comment: I'm with @Lemayzeur.  You need to post more of your code.  I am sure I have ran into this once or twice, but can't remember exactly what it was.  I am sure it was something simple though, otherwise I would remember it :D

Comment: @isaac328 a full stack trace would be super helpful as well.

Comment: @isaac328 you still miss the point, all your URLs should end with `$`. except for the `base url` which contains `include`, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You say "It works as intended on the built-in Django development server but fails when deployed to the production server".

To me, this indicates a problem with the deployment on the production server that does not exist on the development server. For example, maybe on the production server, you are using a web server such as Apache or NGINX that you are not using on development.

I would check and double check any infrastructure such as web servers, load balancers, etc that gets the request before Django does, and make sure it isn't rewriting the path or otherwise passing incorrect configuration to Django.